# How to define EJB JAX-RS web service with no concurrent behaviour

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have a rest web service implemented by an EJB. The service consist of an interface and a implementation:

```
@Remote
@Path(value="bidsystem")
@PermitAll
public interface BidSystemRemote extends InterfaceRemote<Bid> {

  @POST
  @Path(value = "addbid")
  @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  @Consumes(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
  @PermessiNecessari(operation = STANDARD_OP.UPDATE)
  public void addbid(
        @FormParam(value = "iduser") Long iduser, 
        @FormParam(value = "value") Double value) 
        throws BadRequestException;
  ...
}

@Stateless
@PermitAll
public class BidSystemImpl implements BidSystemRemote {

   public void addbid(Long iduser,Double value) throws BadRequestException {
    ...
   }
}
```

When an user call /bidsistem/addbid, a bid is placed. An user can place bid only if the last bid value is less than passed value.

So, current value is 100; A place a bid 101, bid accepted.

If B send 105 and C send 102 in the same moment, two threads start and the bids are accepted (105>101; 102>101 )... but C bid is wrong.

How can I execute the request one at time?

I know that I can do that with a **@Singleton** class, but this class has other methods performing readings and I want to execute them concurrently.

I can move the addbid method in an other class, but i want to use less url s root (for example, now I have bidsystem/list, bidsystem/last, bidsystem/addbid, if I move the method, I will have bidsystem2/addbid )

Comment: You can limit the number of concurrent thread of your application server to 1 or use `synchronized` in your bussines method to allow just one thread being executed at the same time `public syncrhonized void addbid`. `Singleton` pattern is not useful here. I am not sure if EJB interface can deal with `synchronized`. If not, you can set the synchronized before or after the EJB

Comment: @pedrofb synchronized is at instance level, if you have more instance of EJB in the pool, they are executed concurrently.  You need only one instance in the pool.
One instance in the pool is like using Singleton and that work (using also @Lock(WRITE) on method)

Comment: Reading the documentation of @Lock, it blocks the full bean, so you could translate the concurrent methods to other EJB (if it is possible) not locked, or set a `synchronized` wrapper method before EJB call